# How to send Cell Broadcast message in Java ME development environment?

Tags: java-me, nokia, wma, java-wireless-toolkit

I have been trying to develop a Java ME application using WTK 2.5.2 (Java Wireless Toolkit) and Nokia SDK 3. The application would broadcast a CBS (Cell Broadcast Service) message using the WMA (Wireless Messaging API).

Documentations says that the CBS messages are read-only, thus it can not been sent. When I tried to send myself, it threw an exception.

Is there anyone who has some experience with the problem please inform me!

Is there anyway to do this with another SDK or even mimick it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handset is capable of receiving CBS messages, not sending them.  They are sent on a many-to-one basis by the operator.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast) for more info.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am aware of the situation actually. I just wanted to know if it is possible (maybe with a different SDK) to send CBS broadcast message from a device (with special SIM card) maybe.

My application is based consists of multiple devices listening CBS on a special port and one device makes broadcast to them.